# Краш каждые 10 секунд

Tags: android

На телефоне каждые десять секунд влетает краш,ничего не могу сделать, работал на телефоне не могу, помогите[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не по теме, но на моем LG такая же фигня с утра была, помогло удаление обновлений приложения "Google"

Comment: @ermak0ff плей?

Comment: нет, не плей, приложение так и называется - "Google"

Comment: вот уже и видосы запилили:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HStkt-GQqNg&ab_channel=SOTOV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поможет обновление приложения [Google](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) из маркета Google Play